# Sentry send notification SystemExit: 1

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn, sentry

On web server I'm using Python3.6, Django with Gunicorn and Supervisor. After deploy to server I began to receive notifications from Sentry like this:

> Message
>
> SystemExit: 1

Sentry log: https://sentry.io/share/issue/ddd8c6426d68494facfa0bdab9b01a2c/

What can be reason of this?

Comment: Please add more logs to identify the problem.

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl added full log link

Comment: Please update your question with the corresponding part from `views.py` & `models.py` of `/projects/queue/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be too late to answer this. I had the same issue. It turns out to be caused by `gunicorn` thread timeout for long-running tasks.

To fix the issue add this to gunicorn config file:

```
--timeout 120
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the issue, my solution was that I needed to add the SSL environment var:
`EMAIL_USE_SSL=True`